# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “end-of-file” in simple update block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Im trying below query

```
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO
        WEB_FE_USER_QUERY(
            LISTING_ID ,
            QUERY_NAME ,
            USER_PREFERENCE ,
            USER_CRITERIA ,
            DEFAULT_QUERY ,
            CREATED_DATE_TIME ,
            IS_GLOBAL
        )
    VALUES(
        '0' ,
        'NovatedTrades' ,
        'test' ,
        'test' ,
        0 ,
        TO_DATE(
            '2013-06-14 20:28:16' ,
            'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
        ) ,
        0
    );
END;
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong with that sql please??

Comment: Forgot to put a slash a the end?

Comment: I added it now and still it giving below error. :(

   
  ORA-06550: line 23, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ;

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the SQL you're showing us?  Is there more?  Can you run the INSERT alone (outside of a BEGIN/END block)?

Comment: It looks like the insert alone works fine in SQL Fiddle: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4be24/1/0). I'm not a big PLSQL guy though so my help kind of ends here

Comment: Where and now are you running this - which client and version, and if it's an IDE, which window? E.g. in SQL Developer, is this just in a SQL Worksheet?

Comment: Are you [using SQuirreL](http://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/mailman/message/2956442/), perhaps? (It's taken me a while to remember where I'd seen this behaviour before...)

Comment: im Using DBeaver.. and seems that is the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DBeaver [apparently doesn't support PL/SQL](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=680). That's an old thread, [but still seems to be true](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1624).

From the behaviour you're seeing it seems to be treating the semicolons as statement separators, and is passing everything up to the the first semicolon (i.e. up to `)` before `; END;`) to Oracle, which does parse that fragment as PL/SQL.

You can generate the same error in SQL Developer by omitting the code after the first semicolon, or by selecting the text up to that, and trying to run it:

```
...
        ) ,
        0
    )
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 23, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ;
```

Probably not what you want to hear, but it looks like you'll need to use a different client to run PL/SQL blocks. [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) is free and is pretty good these days. Other clients are available of course...

Answer (score 0):

it works by adding block delimiters.
--/ before the code starts
/  after the end of the code :

```
--/
declare
v_char varchar2(20);
v_count INTEGER:= 1;
begin
 while v_count < 10
 loop
  dbms_output.put_line('testing loop'||v_count);
  v_count := v_count + 1;
 end loop;
end;
/
```